# How to get ride of this error during compilation on mac?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

Good morning,
I'm having some issue during the compilation of my project on mac. I'm using a `Makefile` for the compilation and when I execute the `make` command, I have errors that come up. The problem is that under a docker, the compilation works perfectly fine but for this project I need to compile it under my mac because I'm using a library which is not installed under my docker and I don't have time for that for the moment. I think it's probably because the shell is using `clang` for the compilation and I'm used to use `GCC`. I'm totally new under mac so I don't know what I should do to avoid that.

```
MY_INFO$ make
c++    -c -o *.o Input.cpp
In file included from Input.cpp:8:
In file included from ./Input.hpp:11:
./Error.hpp:19:9: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
        ~Error() = default;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:101:13: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual ~exception() _NOEXCEPT;
            ^
In file included from Input.cpp:8:
In file included from ./Input.hpp:11:
./Error.hpp:19:20: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        ~Error() = default;
                   ^
./Error.hpp:21:17: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
    const char *what() const noexcept {return _msg;}
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:102:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char* what() const _NOEXCEPT;
                        ^
In file included from Input.cpp:8:
In file included from ./Input.hpp:11:
./Error.hpp:21:29: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    const char *what() const noexcept {return _msg;}
                            ^
                            ;
./Error.hpp:18:15: error: member initializer '_msg' does not name a non-static data member or base class
            : _msg(msg), _file(file), _line(line) {}
              ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from Input.cpp:8:
./Input.hpp:18:9: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
        ~InputSoundError() = default;
        ^
./Error.hpp:19:9: note: overridden virtual function is here
        ~Error() = default;
        ^
In file included from Input.cpp:8:
./Input.hpp:18:30: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
        ~InputSoundError() = default;
                             ^
2 warnings and 5 errors generated.
make: *** [*.o] Error 1

MY_INFO$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

As follow, my makefile.

```
SRC     =   *.cpp
OBJ     =   $(foreach source, $(SRC), $(source:.cpp=.o))
NAME    =   SoundTest
CFLAGS  =   -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11
LDFLAGS =   -lportaudio
CC      =   g++
LD      =   g++

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

Comment: Does `std::cout << "C++ is " << __cplusplus << "\n";` output 201703?

Comment: @Eljay the output is `199711`

Comment: I don't think your `obj/%.o: %.cpp` rule is being used because you're actually trying to build `foo.o` from `foo.cpp` -- not `obj/foo.o`.  That being the case a built-in rule is being used which isn't making use of `CFLAGS`.  Try changing the definition of `OBJ` to `OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SRC))` .  Also change the definition of `SRC` to `SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile has a few issues.  Firstly, you can't glob filenames using `*.cpp` -- `make` has its own function for that so you should use...

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

You can also check the value of the `SRC` variable with something like...

```
$(info SRC=[$(SRC)])
```

Next, your rule to build object files is...

```
obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

So for any given source file `foo.cpp` this rule tells make how to build `obj/foo.o` from that source file.  But you specify the list of object files based on the source file names using...

```
OBJ = $(foreach source, $(SRC), $(source:.cpp=.o))
```

So if `SRC` is, e.g. `a.cpp b.cpp` then `OBJ` is `a.o b.o` *not* `obj/a.o obj/b.o` as would be required to make use of the `obj/%.o: %.cpp` rule.  What you really want is for `OBJ` to be `obj/a.o obj/b.o` (by way of example) so the variable definition should be...

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SRC))
```

Putting the bits together gives...

```
SRC     =   $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ     =   $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SRC))
NAME    =   SoundTest
CFLAGS  =   -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11
LDFLAGS =   -lportaudio
CC      =   g++
LD      =   g++

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the content of your Makefile, we can see that you simply call

`c++    -c -o *.o Input.cpp`

from it. I have no idea what your compiler is and also not it`s version, maybe it is an older clang.

As we see a lot of warnings containing "are a C++11 extension" you should try to add `--std=c++11` somewhere in the Makefile. Typically you find a line like `CXXFLAGS+=...`. Here you can add the `--std=c++11` flags to use c++11.

Maybe your compiler is to old and did not have full c++11 support. In this case, you have to update.

For a more detailed answer, we need your Makefile and the given compiler including the version.

Comment: I updated the post. the `std=c++11` was already  there and still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @hissroth • Odd that you have `--std=c++11` yet `__cplusplus` is `199711`.

Comment: yes,  but is there a way to change the version of my c++ there ?